# ¿Cómo vincular y mostrar un template personalizado?

Tags: html5, python-3.x, django-urls

Se trata de un pequeño blog en el que trato que desde la página de inicio 'home' a través de un enlace dentro de una 'tarjeta' este pueda dirigirse a una página donde  muestra el detalle de un tema X.

[image: Tarjeta en Home, enlace: Keep Reading]  [image: Detalla de la publicacion]

El problema es que cuando recorro con un for el diccionario muestra todas las 
publicaciones en pantalla. 
Solo necesito que muestre la publicación de enlace que esta en la tarjeta

card_home.html
Template del home, aquí se construye la vista de la tarjeta.

```
<div class="container my-5">
        <div class="row">
            {% for publication in publications %}
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
                    <div class="card" style="max-width: 540px;">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <img class="card-img" src="{{ publication.image.url }}" alt="image">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ publication.title }} </h4>
                                <p class="card-text">
                                    <small class="text-muted">
                                        {{ publication.published | date:'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT' }}
                                    </small>
                                </p>
                                <p class="card-text lead text-justify">
                                    {{ publication.content | truncatewords:15 | safe }}
                                </p>
                                <a class="card-link" href="{% url 'blog_post_pages' %}"> Keep reading </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Pages_blog.html
Template al que es redireccionado cada enlace que se presenta en cada tarjeta. Pero al hacer click en un enlace dentro de la tarjeta me redirecciona a la página donde están todas las publicaciones y quiero que solo redireccione a una publicación la cual guarda relación con la tarjeta.

```
{% for publication in publications %}

    <div class="container my-5">
        <div class="shadow-sm p-5 mx-2 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <span class="badge badge-primary"> Status:
                            {{ publication.status }}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7"></div>
                    <div class="col-3 text-muted">
                        Published:
                        {{ publication.published | date:'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT' }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="display-3 mt-5 text-center"> {{ publication.title }} </h1>
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="text-center my-5"> {{ publication.subtitle }} </p>
            </blockquote>
            <p class="lead text-justify"> {{ publication.content | safe }} </p>

            <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-white text-muted">
                <p class="font-weight-bold"> Author: </p>
                {{ publication.author }}
                <p class="font-weight-bold mt-4"> Category: </p>
                {% for category in publication.category.all %}
                    {{ category.name }} {% if not forloop.last %} , {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <p class="font-weight-bold mt-4"> Sources: </p>
                {{ publication.sources }}
            </div>

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <div class="text-center mt-5">
                    <a href="{% url 'admin:blog_publication_change' publication.id %}">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="button">
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

view.py

```
# Create your views here.
def blog_start_cards(request):
    publications = Publication.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/blogstartcards.html', {'publications': publications})

def blog_post_pages(request):
    publications = Publication.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpostpages.html', {'publications': publications})
```